# Refactor two steps to avoid redundancy

Tags: c#, refactoring

We have a specification where we

1. build 84 configurations
2. define 167 relations between the 84 configurations
3. add all of the 84 configurations to one joint configuration

My issue is twofold:

- I find the last part repetitive: We're using 84 LOC on adding all the configurations to the joint one.
- When we add a new configuration, we often forget this caveat of adding the new configuration to the joint one.

My own trail of thought has been to combine the first step and third step, but I haven't found a way of doing that while still being able to refer to the configurations for the second step.

**Do you have any suggestions on how to improve this?**

The relevant parts of the code looks like this:

```
var x = X.Build()
var y = Y.Build()
var z = Z.Build()
// 84 times

x.AddRelation(y)
x.AddRelation(z)
// 167 times

var config = new Config(...) {
    Entities =
    {
        x,
        y,
        z,
        // 84 times
    }
}
```

Comment: What configuration system are you using? Something custom? If so you might want to include some more type definitions. It is certainly possible to create a class with a method that both creates, registers, and returns a configuration, but it is difficult to tell if that is practical without seeing more of the code.

Comment: I concur with Jonas. Also What types are Big X and small x?

Comment: And when you say 167 relations could you be more exact? Like in your example it looks like one would just put everything in relation with x but then you couldnt do that 167 times. Or does one have to add every relation to x and then all configs still need to add x to themselves? In the latter case one could do a workaround with an extension Method

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of Detail this is the best I can give you atm.

```
//since I dont know the Details of how this will have to look im just doing some guesswork here
public Config Builder(List<ConfigurationToBuild> configsToBuild)
{
    List<BuildConfig> buildConfigs = new List<BuildConfig>();
    foreach(ConfigurationToBuild cTB in configsToBuild)
    {
        buildConfigs.Add(cTB.Build());
    }
    
    BuildConfig relationConfig = buildConfigs[0];
    bool skip = true;
    
    foreach(BuildConfig bC in buildConfigs)
    {
        if(skip)
        {
            skip = false;
            continue;
        }
        
        relationConfig.AddRelationSingular(bC);
    }
    
    //I will run on the assumtion that Entities is a List
    
    var config = new Config(...)
    {
        Entities = buildConfigs
    };
    
    return config;
}

public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static void AddRelationSingular(this BuildConfig config, BuildConfig configToAdd)
    {
        config.AddRelation(configToAdd);
        configToAdd.AddRelation(config);
    }
}
```